# Getting media file name without download it

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I'm using `telethon` to download media from groups and i'm generating a noSQL element using `tinyDB`. Now I need to *recrawl* the entire db and add the filename but I don't know if it is possible to get the file name without 
downloading it using `client.download_media()`

Comment: Could you share some code to let us know what you already tried?

Comment: @Jones1220
`
for chatObject in chatNames:
   for message in client.iter_messages(username):
      dl = client.download_media(message, 'media/')
`
where `chatNames` is an array of chat names